# Selecionar todos checkbox ao clicar em outro checkbox do PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Estou com uma dúvida, como selecionar todos checkbox que esteja dentro de um panelgrid? Eu vi que é possível fazer isso via javaScript.

Mas fiquei em duvida sobre como executar o método porque para selecionar todos. De primeiro queria ver se realmente pegava. Aí fiz o metodo para selecionar a partir do id do panelgrid.

Mas não sei como executar o metodo no primefaces.

Estou usando o componente `p:selectManyCheckbox`.

```
<p:panelGrid styleClass="panelGridCenter" style="width:70%">
    <p:row>
        <p:column >
            <p:panelGrid id="panelEstados" styleClass="panelGridCenter">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column styleClass="columnCenter">
                        <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{lojaBean.pojo.ufsInss}" layout="grid" columns="4" >
                            <f:selectItems value="#{lojaBean.helper.estados}"/>
                            <f:selectItem id="checkBoxTodas" itemLabel="Todas" itemValue="false"/>
                        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Assim como realizar tal feito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A grande dificuldade ao se fazer customizações com Javascript em páginas JSF é que não temos controle sobre o HTML gerado para o browser. Tanto a estrutura como os IDs dos componentes não estão sob nosso controle, e assim torna-se difícil fazer referência a eles em um script.

O que costumo fazer é procurar alguns padrões no HTML gerado, e montar o script baseado nesses padrões. Nesse caso eu faria uma solução como a seguinte:

Pegar os elementos cujo ID contém "checkBoxTodas" . O JSF gera IDs próprios para eles, mas todos contém o ID que você especificou.
Para cada um desses elementos, adicionar o seguinte procedimento no click:
(1) Obter a célula da tabela onde ele está contido. Ou seja, pesquisar nos elementos pai até achar um "td" que possua class=columnCenter
(2) Obter todos os checkboxes contidos nesse TD.
(3) Marcar esses checkboxes com o mesmo valor que está no checkbox clicado (checkBoxTodas).

Parece trabalhoso, mas o jQuery facilita muito a vida, fica na verdade bastante simples. Veja aqui um exemplo simulando esse caso:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--
    Na página feita com PrimeFaces nao é preciso o trecho abaixo para 
    importar o JQuery, ele vem de brinde.
    -->
    <script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript">

      /**
      * Funcao a ser disparada quando o checkbox checkBoxTodas for clicado.
      */
      function checkBoxTodas_onClick() {
        // Localiza a celula de class "columnCenter" que esta imediatamente superior
        var parentTd = $(this).parents(".columnCenter").first();

        // Pega referência a todos os filhos que são checkboxes
        var checkboxes = parentTd.find("input[type=checkbox]");

        // Estado do checkbox TODAS
        var check = $(this).is(":checked");

        // Atribui esse mesmo estado aos demais checkboxes
        checkboxes.prop("checked", check);
      }

      /**
      * Adiciona a funcao acima como event handler para todos os checkboxes cujo ID
      * contem "checkBoxTodas".
      * O JSF gerara ids diferentes para cada ocorrencia, mas todos contem a 
      * tal String.
      */
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[id*="checkBoxTodas"]').click(checkBoxTodas_onClick);
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!--
      O trecho abaixo simula aproximadamente o HTML gerado pelo codigo JSF.
      O checkbox com id="checkBoxTodas" acaba recebendo no HTML um ID bem mais complicado,
      que geralmente não está sob nosso controle.
    -->
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td class="columnCenter">
          A <input type="checkbox" />
          B <input type="checkbox" />
          C <input type="checkbox" />
          D <input type="checkbox" />
          E <input type="checkbox" />
          <br />

          <input type="checkbox" id="form1:panelEstados:checkBoxTodas:blablabla"></input>
          <label for="form1:panelEstados:checkBoxTodas:blablabla">Todas</label>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor como chamo o método no componente? Posso incluir isso em um arquivo separado...

Comment: Não precisa chamar no componente. Essa linha `$('input[id*="checkBoxTodas"]').click(checkBoxTodas_onClick);` é que fica responsável por procurar os elementos que tem "checkBoxTodas" no ID, e então inclui o tratamento para eventos de click.
Então só colando esse script na página já deve funcionar (ou quase, talvez na página real precise de pequenos ajustes mas depois de entender o que o código está fazendo vai ser fácil)

Comment: Sim, preciso fazer alguns ajustes, porque é o seguinte, há outras colunas na página que usam `styleClass="columnCenter"` e ai vou pegar pelo id que vou setar no `selectManyCheckbox`. Até conversei com um cara e ele me disse que o Jquery é simples, é porque eu não tenho as manhas de usar. Mas é o seguinte, gostaria de colocar este código em um arquivo separado entende? Tem como chamar o metodo em algum evento?

Comment: Para adicionar em um arquivo separado é o padrão mesmo, basta colocar o script no arquivo e na página que usa incluí-lo com `<script src="meu_script.js"></script>`

Não precisa chamar nenhum script, porque o evento document.onready vai executar automaticamente ao carregar a página.

Comment: Pois é, cara, obrigado, eu consegui via `Js`, mas vou passar o metodo para `jQuery`.

Comment: é muito estranho. Mas ao tentar utilizar o `JQuery`, no `Primefaces` ele não executa nenhuma função, ele chama um arquivo `jQuery` e fica travado numa função.

Answer (score -1):

FOR JSF 2 ,for selected all rows on datable in selectionMode multiple with paginator=true: In Page

```
<p:dataTable widgetVar="tableArea" yourtags...>
     <p:ajax  event="toggleSelect" oncomplete="teste()" /> /// toggleSelect is dispared on click to checkbox header
     <p:column id="columnId" selectionMode="multiple"/>
```

In js:

function teste(){

```
var checked = $(document).find(":checkbox")["0"].checked; ///Find checkbox header and verify if checkbox is checked
if(checked == true){
    PF('tableArea').selectAllRows(); // if true, selectAllRows from datatable
} else {
    PF('tableArea').unselectAllRows(); //
}
```

}

Segue link do post original:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585080/how-to-create-effective-select-all-checkbox-in-jsf/40889629#40889629

Comment: Bem vindo a comunidade stackoverlow em português. Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência. Como por exemplo, como realizar esta implementação.

Comment: Vou corrigir o post.